# create subplot with loop

Tags: matlab, loops, plot, subplot

i have following question and please help me to solve  following task:

i want to create subplot  in matlab  which  depend on loop variable,for example as i know   to crate plot menu  2X2,we are doing like this

```
subplot(2,2,1)
```

`subplot(2,2,2`)

```
subplot(2,2,3)

subplot(2,2,4)
```

but can i do linear form?like 1:100?or something like this  ,more generally like this

```
n=100;

for i=1:n

subplot(1,n,i)
```

?

thanks very much

EDITED   CODE

```
function [order]=find_order(y,fs);
order=0;
n=length(y);
n1=nextpow2(n);
ndft=2^n1;
for i=1:floor(n/2)
    [Pxx,f]=pburg(y,i,ndft,fs);
    subplot(ndft,ndft,i);
    plot(f,Pxx);
    title(['order',num2str(i),'i']);
    order=i;    
end
end


   picture :
```

[image]

i can't understand what happens

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: no generally,i  want just to  see if it is possible

Comment: maybe   subplot window is small ?

Comment: Typical length of `y`, i.e. the first input argument to the function in the edited code?

Comment: sorry which one? n? fs is sampling rate

Comment: Try this - `subplot(floor(n/2),1,i);`

Comment: Yes, just like the 1-D demo in my answer, because you are using one for loop.

Comment: but it does not  work

Comment: no,just something mixed picture,,like in my case

Comment: maybe there would be   such solution,to save this pictures  all in one word document,how can i do this?or it is better to accept this answer to my old question and post new one?

Comment: Yeah I guess if you want to do pictures and word document stuffs, putting up a new question would be sensible.

Comment: **Suggestion1:** Try with a small `y` like `4` or `6`. Intention is to keep the number of subplots less.
**Suggestion2:** Try with `subplot(floor(n/2),1,i);`
**Suggestion3:** Remove `title(['order',num2str(i),'i']);` until the subplots work.

Comment: no y is  signal given by  deterministic component+noise,it is  large-294  sample size

Comment: there is another solution maybe:show pictures but with some second pause,is it possible

Comment: see please this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886653/subplot-multiple-output-with-large-sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1-D Demo**

**Code**

```
%%// Data
t = 0:0.01:15*pi;
y1 = sin(t);

%%// Plot
figure,
for k=1:4
    subplot(4,1,k)
    plot(t((k-1)*1000+1:k*1000),y1((k-1)*1000+1:k*1000))
    xlim([0 40])
end
```

**Output**

[image]

**2-D Demo**

**Code**

```
%%// Data
t = 0:0.01:15*pi;
y1 = sin(t);

%%// Plot
colors=['r' 'g' ; 'y' 'k'];

figure,
for k1=1:2
    for k2=1:2
        subplot(2,2,(k1-1)*2+k2)
        plot(t,y1,colors(k1,k2));
    end
end
```

**Output**

[image]

Hopefully these demos would guide to you something meaningful for your case.

Comment: when  sizes are large and it can't held all picture,what i should do?

Comment: Sure, let's take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is:

```
n=5;

for i=1:n

subplot(1,n,i)

end
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for pat=1: N  % main loop

```
% Define the sublot grid
s1=3; % subplot rows
s2=3; % subplot columns

% find the figure number
fig_num=floor(pat/(s1*s2))+1 % Figure number

% Find the subplot number
sub_fig=mod(pat,s1*s2)   % subplot number

% correct for corners
if(sub_fig==0)
    sub_fig=s1*s2;
    fig_num=fig_num-1;
end

% plot something
figure(fig_num);
subplot(s1,s2,sub_fig) ;

plot(1,1) % plot something
```

end % of main loop